# How to extract images from pdf using iText7 c#

Tags: c#, .net, itext7

Below approach i have used to extract images from pdf. But sub type is always giving null. I am working with iText7 library which is new version. If any body worked with new library please give suggestions.

```
    public static string ExtractImageFromPDF(string sourcePdf)
    {            
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(sourcePdf);
        try
        {
            PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(reader);

            for (int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= document.GetNumberOfPages(); pageNumber++)
            {
                PdfDictionary obj = (PdfDictionary)document.GetPdfObject(pageNumber);

                if (obj != null && obj.IsStream())
                {
                    PdfDictionary pd = (PdfDictionary)obj;
                    if (pd.ContainsKey(PdfName.Subtype) && pd.Get(PdfName.Subtype).ToString() == "/Image")
                    {
                        string filter = pd.Get(PdfName.Filter).ToString();
                        string width = pd.Get(PdfName.Width).ToString();
                        string height = pd.Get(PdfName.Height).ToString();
                        string bpp = pd.Get(PdfName.BitsPerComponent).ToString();
                        string extent = ".";
                        byte[] img = null;
                        switch (filter)
                        {
                            case "/FlateDecode":
                                byte[] arr = FlateDecodeFilter.FlateDecode(null, true);
                                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Int32.Parse(width), Int32.Parse(height), PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
                                BitmapData bmd = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, Int32.Parse(width), Int32.Parse(height)), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
                                    PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
                                Marshal.Copy(arr, 0, bmd.Scan0, arr.Length);
                                bmp.UnlockBits(bmd);
                                bmp.Save("d:\\pdf\\bmp1.png", ImageFormat.Png);
                                break;
                            case "/CCITTFaxDecode":
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: "it is returning null" nothing in the code you've posted returns null.

Comment: Sorry, sub type is always coming as null value.

Comment: You mean `pd.Get(PdfName.Subtype).ToString() == null`?

Comment: Yes, it is giving null.

Comment: the correct is document.GetPdfObject(objectNumber), not document.GetPdfObject(pageNumber)

Answer (score 0):

When you use Quickwatch on the pd value, what do you see is in there? The documentation of the iText 7 states is a dictionary, so perhaps you can check which types are available and find the appropriate field that you're looking for.

```
PdfDictionary pd = (PdfDictionary)obj;
```

Documentation can be found overhere:
https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/7.1.8/classi_text_1_1_kernel_1_1_pdf_1_1_pdf_dictionary.html

Answer (score 0):

The idea of your approach is to check *every indirect object* in it whether it is an image XObject and extract the contained image data therein if it is.

Actually, though, you only iterate over the values `1`..`document.GetNumberOfPages()` as object numbers, i.e. only over a fraction of the indirect objects of your document!

Indeed, there are more indirect objects in a PDF than there are pages, usually very many more.

Thus, iterate instead up to `document.GetNumberOfPdfObjects()-1`.